# Hosting widgets getting java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial error

Tags: java, android, widget, runtime-error

I am making an app that hosts widgets and it works well except for when I add the email widget. When I do that I get a java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial error : starting intent.

Here is the error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=11, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {aheschl.screenscortcut/aheschl.screenscortcut.WidgetEdge}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE cmp=com.samsung.android.email.provider/com.samsung.android.email.widget.EmailWidgetConfig (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{af0a74c 10759:aheschl.screenscortcut/u0a319} (pid=10759, uid=10319) not exported from uid 10033
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4926)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4969)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1850)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE cmp=com.samsung.android.email.provider/com.samsung.android.email.widget.EmailWidgetConfig (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{af0a74c 10759:aheschl.screenscortcut/u0a319} (pid=10759, uid=10319) not exported from uid 10033
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3131)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4284)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4231)
                                                                        at aheschl.screenscortcut.WidgetEdge.configureWidget(WidgetEdge.java:124)
                                                                        at aheschl.screenscortcut.WidgetEdge.onActivityResult(WidgetEdge.java:94)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7138)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4922)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4969) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1850) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7230) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Here is the method configureWidget which is mentioned in the log

```
private void configureWidget(Intent data) {
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
    AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetInfo = mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(appWidgetId);
    if (appWidgetInfo.configure != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
        intent.setComponent(appWidgetInfo.configure);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET);

    } else {
        createWidget(data);
    }
}
```

And here is onActivityResult()

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET) {
            configureWidget(data);
        } else if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CREATE_APPWIDGET) {
            createWidget(data);
        } else if(requestCode == Constants.RESIZE_WIDGETS_CODE){
            //getParams
            int height = data.getIntExtra("height", 100);
            int width = data.getIntExtra("width", 100);
            receivedHeight = height;
            receivedWidth = width;
            waitingForResult = false;
        }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data != null) {
        int appWidgetId = data.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);
        if (appWidgetId != -1) {
            mAppWidgetHost.deleteAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like Samsung screwed up and did not export that configuration activity. Temporarily switch to some other home screen (not yours, not Samsung's) and see if the same sort of crash occurs in LogCat when trying to add the app widget to that home screen. If so, it's definitely Samsung's fault, and there's nothing much that you can do about it.

Comment: I have been using Nova launcher as my default launcher for several months. The email widget works flawlessly on that launcher. Also I forgot to mention that my app is not a replacement launcher. It is a pull out screen(similar to the Samsung edge) that allows you to place widgets. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: "The email widget works flawlessly on that launcher" -- your problem isn't with the app widget itself, but with the configuration activity. That configuration activity works when started from Nova? If so, I cannot explain how this error can come about.

Comment: When placed on Nova launcher the widget launches it's configuration activity and gets shown on the home screen as it's supposed to. Thank you for your suggestions and help.

Comment: @AndrewHeschl, Have you found the solution

Comment: @Fossor unfortunatly not

Comment: @AndrewHeschl It happens with other widgets too, one of them is evernote widget. It somehow works in launchers that extend launcher3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question but I think I found the solution.

I was wondering how can activities with `exported = "false"` tags still be called by some launchers.
There is a method [`startAppWidgetConfigureActivityForResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetHost.html#startAppWidgetConfigureActivityForResult(android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) in AppWidgetHost that these launchers use.

> Starts an app widget provider configure activity for result on behalf of the caller. Use this method if the provider is in another profile as you are not allowed to start an activity in another profile. You can optionally provide a request code that is returned in Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) and an options bundle to be passed to the started activity.
>   Note that the provided app widget has to be bound for this method to work.

So not only this method can start activity in another profile, but it also ignores the `exported = "false"` tag. Sounds like a security issue to me.